# Opengl textures and endianness 

Tags: image, opengl, endianness, glteximage2d

I'm using glTexSubImage2D with GL_LUMINANCE and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to display raw greyscale data from a camera directly - rather than having to repack it into an RGB bitmap manually.

I would like to run the camera in higher resolution mode, with 12 or 14bits/ pixel.

I can do this with simply by setting `GL_SHORT` but the camera returns data in big endian and my openGL implementation seems to be drawing it the wrong way around (on x86).

Is there a simple way of telling openGL that the textures are the 'wrong' way round? I would like to avoid manually byteswaping the data just for display because all the other functions  expect big endian data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [glPixelStore*](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml) group of functions.

You might need to play with `GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES` or `GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST` but double check you're using the correct `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`.  By default the unpack alignment is 4, but if you're using one byte per pixel (lum / ub), you'll want to set that to 1.  I ran into this problem just recently, and it took me longer to figure out than I'd care to admit :)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, the first time I encountered this problem I wrote a short GLSL program to fix it. I felt quite foolish when I eventually spotted GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT.

Comment: @Tommy It's also #8 on opengl.org's list of common pitfalls. http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/  Silly Us.

Comment: Excellent - `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES,1);` it is. That's the great thing about openGL, somebody has already solved it - you just need to know where.